# Is there something like Application.ProductVersion for .NET web DLL?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, web-services, wcf

I want to get the version of my .NET web app or web service - the one that shows on the DLL from AssemblyInfo.cs - and will be nice to get other assembly info like company and copyright.

In a Windows app this is easy, you just do Application.ProductVersion to get the version. Is there something similar for web apps/services? Something like System.Web.App.Version?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

For any type inside the assembly you want to get the version from, you can get the version like this:

```
typeof(SomeType).Assembly.GetName().Version
```

For other stuff, like the company and copyright, you have to look up the assembly-level attributes directly.  Here's an example for Copyright:

```
object[] attributes = typeof(SomeType).Assembly
    .GetCustomAttributes(typeof(AssemblyCopyrightAttribute), false);

AssemblyCopyrightAttribute attribute = null;
if (attributes.Length > 0)
{
   attribute = attributes[0] as AssemblyCopyrightAttribute;
}

var companyName = attribute.Company;
```